# MBProgressHUD Displaying and click on button

Tags: ios, mbprogresshud

When `MBProgressHUD` is Display progress, my view user interface disable so user can not click on button.

But when `MBProgressHUD` is in Progress that time if u click on button no button action call. but after `MBProgressHUD` complete process that button click call automatically.

How I can stop that.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
HUD.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

you can change the property as `userInteractionEnabled` as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void) hideProgressHUD
{

        //this for loop will remove all progress hud from window, if user accept multiple notification one by one then for removing hud from screen this for loop is added.

        for (UIView *v in self.window.subviews) {
            if ([v isKindOfClass:[MBProgressHUD class]]) {
                MBProgressHUD *hudV = (MBProgressHUD *)v;
                [hudV hide:YES];
                [hudV removeFromSuperview];

            }
        }

        [hudActivity hide:YES];
        [hudActivity removeFromSuperview];
        hudActivity=nil;
    }
```